# Unity: how to force rotation after rotating towards a direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After asking [here for a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72676816/why-does-this-not-move-properly-the-object), which worked, my sphere "walks" to each point of a list. Now, I'm trying to "force" a rotation around the x axis, to fake the ball is "rolling". I came up with the following code, but it doesn't work (it makes a progressive acceleration of the rotation on the x-axis, which I both dont want and... dont understand).

Create a new project, add a sphere and add this small script. Then add 2 points in the points list. This script does nothing but moving the object (the sphere) each points of the list, and make a simple rotation around the x-axis.

Simple rotation around the x-axis is not realistic (it's working as long as the sphere doesn't change its direction, but in this case, it should rotate on x + on z, but I dont know how to do this too...) so if you have a more realistic idea its even more welcome.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveAlongPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3[] points;
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 200.0f;
    public float minDistance = Vector3.kEpsilon;
    private SphereCollider _c;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _posStart;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _posEnd;
    [SerializeField] private int _currentIndex;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _direction;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _directionNormalized;
    [SerializeField] private float _xRotation;

    private void NextPoint()
    {
        _posStart = points[_currentIndex];
        transform.position = _posStart;
        _currentIndex = ++_currentIndex % points.Length;
        _posEnd = points[_currentIndex];
        _direction = _posEnd - _posStart;
        _directionNormalized = _direction.normalized;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        NextPoint();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _xRotation = (_xRotation + -10 * Time.fixedDeltaTime) % 360;
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.LookRotation(
            _directionNormalized, Vector3.up
        );
        
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
            transform.rotation, q, rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime
        ) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(_xRotation, Vector3.left);
        
        Vector3 step = speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * _directionNormalized;
        if (step.magnitude > _direction.magnitude) {
            step = _direction; // don't overshoot
        } 
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position + step;
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos);
        if (Vector3.Distance(_posEnd, transform.position) < minDistance) {
            /* close enough -> next point: */
            NextPoint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't test right now but I think you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html, or just https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html e.g. `transform.Rotate (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);`

Comment: Ok, this is the straw that broke the camel's back. Not being able to do such a simple thing after 8 hours and 3 years of Unity, I give myself 3 months to try UE5

Comment: Unity is easily one of the most flexible and exposing APIs in the industry. UE uses C++ for scripting, so be prepared for that if you switch, but really the above problem is resolved simply by reading the docs I linked to or watching a tutorial or two.... or even trying the code I posted! `transform.Rotate (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);`